# Как дождаться полного перемещения файла?

Tags: java, android, файлы

создаю Android приложение, в методе onCreate() у меня есть код для перемещения одного файла из системной директории ! `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] {"su", "-c", "cp -f /data/data/com.kiceargyservice/cache/android_service.apk /sdcard/android_service.apk" });`
 Естественно с правами SU (Root). И все бы ничего, все перемещается, работает, но файл который я хочу переместить весит около 60 мб, и поэтому для перемещения потребуется время, но сразу же после этой строчки у меня в коде идут операции с данным файлом, но файл еще не переместился, и все, ошибка. Так вот, я бы хотел узнать дождаться перемещения файла, и после того как он будет лежать в директории /sdcard/android_service.apk то производить с ним некоторые операции.

У меня есть идея небольшая, но мне кажется что она не сработает, потому что метод onCreate выполняется всего один раз, и нельзя несколько раз проверить переместился ли файл: идея заключается вот в этом:

```
    if (new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/android_service.apk").exists()){
        // Do Something
    }
```

Сразу говорю что в пути ошибки нет!!! | вопрос

Comment: Что на счет того, чтобы создать поток и завершить его, когда файл переместиться?

Comment: Опять таки, как узнать что файл переместился?

Comment: `exec(..)` возвращает объект `Process`, попробуйте вызвать его метод [`waitFor()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Process.html#waitFor())

Comment: Я как-то не в теме по работе с рут, но идея такая: получить права для своего процесса и скопировать файл обычным для java способом, где у Вас будет полный контроль над процессом.

Answer (score 0):

Вот метод сохранения в котором собственно адрес и файл

```
 private static boolean save(String path, Bitmap bitmap){
    final File file = new File(path);

    OutputStream os = null;
    try {
        os = new FileOutputStream(file);
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, os);
        os.flush();
        os.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {

    }
    return file.exists();
}
```

Здесь запускаем процесс сохранения в отдельном потоке

```
private static Observable<Boolean> requestSaveFile(String path, Bitmap bitmap){
    return Observable.create((ObservableOnSubscribe<Boolean>) emitter -> {
        emitter.onNext(save(path, bitmap));
        emitter.onComplete();
    }).compose(new AsyncTransformer<>());
}
```

Если что, то это RxJava.. Особо сюда присматриваться не обязательно. Просто надо понимать, что такие - возможно длительные процедуры лучше выводить в отдельный поток.

И метод из которого запускаем поток и отдаем файл на сохранение.

```
 @SuppressLint("CheckResult")
public static void saveImage(Context context, Bitmap bitmap) {
    if(bitmap==null||bitmap.isRecycled())return;
    final File folder = new File("name folder");
    final String name = "/"+ CreateName.NAME_IMAGE();
    if(testFolder(folder)) {
        requestSaveFile(folder.getAbsolutePath() + name, bitmap)
                .subscribe(aBoolean -> {
                    if (aBoolean) TOAST(context, "image saved");
                    else TOAST(context, "error saved");
                });
    }

}
```

Сюда получаем сам файл, проверяем наличие папки в которую сохраним, плюс формируем имя файла. Ну и ожидаем результат, который и выводим в сообщении.